# How to avoid margin references being placed on top of each other in quarto

Tags: r, quarto

[Quarto](https://tutorial.quarto.org/) is designed to supercede Rmarkdown. It supports many languages and offers new features.

One new feature is the ability to place citations and other content in the [right-hand margin](https://quarto-dev.github.io/quarto-gallery/page-layout/tufte.html).

I'm running into an issue where some margin references are being printed on top of existing margin references. As best I can tell, this happens because each new paragraph's margin references are placed directly across from that paragraph, without regard for the length of the previous paragraph's references.

In this first example, only the first paragraph includes references, and they are rendered nicely.

```
---
format: html
reference-location: margin
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur[^1] adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.[^2] Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

[^1]: Here is the first citation. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
[^2]: Here is the second citation.
```

[image]

**Here is the problem**. In this example, I add a reference to the second paragraph. Note #3 should be placed below Note #2. Instead, it is placed directly across from paragraph 2.

```
---
format: html
reference-location: margin
---

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur[^1] adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.[^2] Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.[^3]

[^1]: Here is the first citation. Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
[^2]: Here is the second citation.
[^3]: Here is the third citation.
```

[image]

**How can I make notes from paragraph 2 begin *after* notes from paragraph 1?**

Comment: This was cross posted in the RStudio community also: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-avoid-margin-references-being-placed-on-top-of-each-other-in-quarto/136439

This was an issue: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/834 that has been fixed in version v0.9.382

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of quarto? Your example renders differently for me on 0.9.421:

[image]

Comment: This was cross posted in the RStudio community also: https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-avoid-margin-references-being-placed-on-top-of-each-other-in-quarto/136439 This was an issue: https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/issues/834 that has been fixed in version v0.9.382